# Resolve hostname to IP address for Postfix

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, postfix-mta

I'm trying to setup postfix in a VPC on AWS where an external server communicates with a postfix mail server in the same subnet.

I'm getting an error from postfix every time I try to connect to postfix from an external client.  The error says:

```
warning: hostname example.com does not resolve to address 54.x.xxx.xxx
connect from unknown[54.x.xxx.xxx]
lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[54.x.xxx.xxx]
```

I'm suspecting this is related to the IP address that is being pointed to the hostname.  When I run:

```
dig example.com
```

The 'answer' section outputs this:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com. 60 IN  A 10.0.1.132
```

I've looked at this link: http://www.postfix.org/LINUX_README.html

and I've tried editing /etc/host.conf and the /etc/postfix/main.cf file from that link and a bunch of other things from googling but nothing is working and I still get the same error mentioned above.

Is there a way to configure the VPC or the EC2 instance to point to my public IP address, or can I fix this problem trying to add some more configuration settings for postfix?

Comment: Okay, so where does "example.com" and 54.x.x.x come from?  Is that the postfix machine, the client, or what?  What's in your `/etc/hosts` (not host.conf) file?

Comment: @ Michael - sqlbot "example.com" is the hostname of a SMTP client which contains a web interface which relays emails to the postfix server.  For example, say you have 2 servers: "A" and "B".  "A" would be "example.com" relaying emails to the postfix sever "B" to send out to recipients